# How to query photos.google.com for photos based on EXIF data such as number of pixels?

Tags: google-data-api, google-photos

I have loads of photos that were uploaded in duplicate (from my phone) - in each duplicate pair the file names are the same but one of the photos was compressed down from 8mp to 3.1mp.  I would like to delete those duplicates.

I know this may be a manual process, but I have 1000s of pics so I need a short cut.

I tried using the google data api sample, but it responds with a 404. I suspect this has to do with the fact that PICASA web albums is no longer available.

So what I am trying to achieve is a simple query that will give me all photos that were scaled down. I will then manually go through the list to double check whether it is a duplicate and delete it.

Also, I noticed that one could do searches based on the camera used (from the web UI) - e.g. #nexus5 will return all photos taken with that camera.  Is there a way to do this from here?

Answer (score 0):

If you add your Google Photos directory to Google Drive, and then Sync your Google Drive to your desktop computer you can access all of the EXIF data for the files there, and just delete the images as you see fit.